# Digitally programmable switching regulator design

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

I need to generate a voltage switchable between two levels (5V and 10V) by a microcontroller running at 3.3V. It will be powering lamps at about 1A, low noise is not a major issue.

I have designed the following circuit:

[image]

For 5V/10V output R1=420R, Rx=580R, R2=3k

The black part is from the LM2596 datasheet, the red part is my addition to allow the voltage to be switchable. The MOSFET essentially allows the resistor Rx to be bypassed. The datasheet says R1 should be between 240R and 1.5k so there is room to adjust it.

The other option is to have the extra resistor to ground, like this:

[image]

For 5V/10V output R1=1k, Rx=750R, R2=3k
With the MOSFET on R1/Rx in parallel is 430R equivellent

This seems to be the more popular way of doing it. Is there any advantage to either method?

Answer (score 1):

There's a general disadvantage for using either - any old MOSFET will have significant drain source capacitance and it might turn your nice regulated voltage into a mess of oscillations because the MOSFET capacitance is messing with the carefully designed feedback regime at higher frequencies. Notice \$C_{FF}\$ - it's beneficial effect at stabilizing the regulator may be be lost (or reduced) with significant drain source capacitance. The good news is that there is still a resistor between MOSFET drain and the FB pin. This offers mitigation.

But, if you choose something with low capacitance (possibly an analogue switch) and low leakage (again an analogue switch springs to mind of the right sort), you should have no bother. Of course, any old MOSFET might just be OK so try it.

Comment: I expect it will be fine. I've used something similar based on an app note for a constant current NIMH charger that used FETs to switch resistors to ground to alter the feedback loop. Found it, figure 4: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva557/snva557.pdf

Comment: Yeah that iceburg will be fine said the captain of the titanic in 1912 - @user please don't give advice like this especially when figure 4 in your linked document has 10 kohm between drain and FB pin and an op-amp in the feedback loop. You just can't make sweeping statements like that.

Comment: Section 9.2.2.2.4 of the datasheet gives information on CFF. Unfortunately I don't have PSpice to test it. There are some cheap boards on eBay using this part though so maybe I could  lash something up. Anyway, what would you suggest as an actual alternative solution?

Comment: You might need to increase the capacitor \$C_{FF}\$ but, try it and see.

Comment: @user if you are done with this Q and A now you should formally select an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the 2nd option. Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6ROWe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C1 is most necessary when the output voltage is >=10V, so the capacitance of M1 doesn't enter into it in that configuration, and the influence of Rds(on) is about 1/3 as much as the first configuration, allowing the use of a smaller (and lower capacitance) MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I was thinking of using an AO3400A because it's in the JLPCB basic parts library, Rds(on) is pretty low anyway and I don't need much precision for lamps but worth considering for other applications. I suspect the additional resistance of the transistor may be why this configuration seems to be preferred in app notes.

Comment: 2N7002 (SMT version of 2N7000)  is probably standard too.

Comment: It is. Much higher Rds though. The AO3400A is sub 50mΩ in the worst case.

Comment: And more than 10x the output capacitance.. so a trade-off. My **guess** is either will work fine given the 10n Cff value.  The 65 or 70mV change in the 10V nominal output for 10 ohms change in Rds  is not big compared to the tolerances. I used 1.25V Vref for the resistor calculations rather than 1.23, for example.

Comment: Good point, the 2N7002 is a better option.